# Why does the address get redirected to port 8080 instead of port 80?

Tags: apache, docker, load-balancing, docker-machine

I am trying to configure the apache load balancer on the docker container with enabled exposing port 80:80. Even load balancer configuration has been updated in load balancer config file with proper ips. Since the whole setup is working in same subnet they all are connected to each other. I am using wordpress image for web server , MySQL image for db and centos image for load balancer,even the firewall rule to masquerade has been done and port to enabled...Pls help

[My loadbalancer config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwrOV.png)

[docker ps command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkz3t.png)

[Error ...Why is it going to port 8080 even though I have configured 80 in loadbalancer file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eVJ5.png)

Comment: Which docker containers corresponds to IP  ```172.17.0.4``` and ```172.17.0.3``` ? wpos and wpos2 ?

Comment: The ips that you mentioned are web servers which I want to connect, and wpos and wpos2 are their names as in 172.17.0.4=wpos2 and 172.17.0.3=wpos

Answer (score 1):

As I can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eVJ5.png), you are trying to access `172.17.0.4:8080` on the browser. And IP `172.17.0.4` corresponds to the container `wpos2`. Now since you had not exposed the port `8080` of this container so the request is not being served from the browser.

Instead, you should try accessing the load balancer container `lb1` using the public IP of your host machine.

Try this: `<HOST_IP>:80`

This will hit your load balancer and from there the request will be redirected to one of the two servers: `wpos` or `wpos2` and you should probably get your request served.

Comment: Actually I am trying to access the 172.17.0.4 and 172.17.0.3 on port 80 since the service is working on port 80 on webserver. One which you recommended works fine no issues with single server  but the whole idea of using load balancer would be of no use right, by exposing the port on host machine

Comment: Yes, you are right -  `the whole idea of using load balancer would be of no use right, by exposing the port on host machine`. But then why are you trying to access the webservers directly using -  `172.17.0.4:80` or `172.17.0.3:80` ?  You should access the load balancer using `host_ip:80` instead of directly accessing the web-servers. Direct access to webservers is not possible because the ports of the webserver are not exposed and we don't want to expose them. In short - Try accessing `host_ip:80` instead of `172.17.0.4:80` or `172.17.0.3:80`.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same you can check that in docker ps command screenshot port 80:80 has be exposed of lb1 but when is try to access by host_ip:80 it goes to load balancer config file takes the first ip but routes to 8080 port rather than 80 that is where I am stuck